# Problem installing pandas-profiling on jupyter on Mac

Tags: python, pandas

So for a class, I had to install pandas and then pandas-profiling. I was able to install it on my Mac, but a classmate needed help, and I was unable to get it to install on her Mac. Our professor could not help as he has a PC. I have both so I was trying to help her. Not sure why it worked on mine and not hers, but it was getting an error no one recognized.

This was the error:
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`
and then more errors followed. Not sure if I should post the whole thing, if needed I can. If you need any more additional information please let me know!

Thank you in advance!

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-me1smeod/numpy_33359d74c576422d9e92794f018182f0/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-me1smeod/numpy_33359d74c576422d9e92794f018182f0/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-record-yazcmtv_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-7ukdk2iz/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-7ukdk2iz/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.

---

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/08/278c6ee569458e168096f6b51019cc1c81c288da3d1026a22ee2ccead102/Bottleneck-1.3.2.tar.gz#sha256=20179f0b66359792ea283b69aa16366419132f3b6cf3adadc0c48e2e8118e573 (from https://pypi.org/simple/bottleneck/). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-8qzzf4p0/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-7ukdk2iz/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.

Using cached Bottleneck-1.3.1.tar.gz (88 kB)

Installing build dependencies ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-c10se9ft/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-9eve9y_3/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''

```
   cwd: None
```

Complete output (262 lines):

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "2.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "2.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Collecting setuptools

```
Using cached setuptools-58.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (816 kB)
```

Collecting wheel

```
Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
```

Collecting numpy==1.14.5

```
Using cached numpy-1.14.5.zip (4.9 MB)
```

Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, numpy

```
  Running setup.py install for numpy: started

  Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-record-xmqdnd8z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-9eve9y_3/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-9eve9y_3/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy

       cwd: /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/

  Complete output (239 lines):

  Running from numpy source directory.



  Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install

  with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:



    - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source

                             release)

    - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)





  /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:464: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)

  blas_opt_info:

  blas_mkl_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  blis_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries blis not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  openblas_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:

  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries tatlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_3_10_blas_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries satlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_blas_threads_info:

  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_blas_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



    FOUND:

      extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']

      extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

      define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]



  /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found

  non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

  /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found

  F2PY Version 2

  lapack_opt_info:

  lapack_mkl_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  openblas_lapack_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  openblas_clapack_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_3_10_threads_info:

  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_3_10_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_threads_info:

  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>

    NOT AVAILABLE



  atlas_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>

    NOT AVAILABLE



    FOUND:

      extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']

      extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

      define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]



  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

    warnings.warn(msg)

  running install

  running build

  running config_cc

  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

  running config_fc

  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

  running build_src

  build_src

  building py_modules sources

  creating build

  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9

  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy

  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils

  building library "npymath" sources

  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pg']'

  customize Gnu95FCompiler

  Could not locate executable gfortran

  Could not locate executable f95

  customize NAGFCompiler

  customize AbsoftFCompiler

  Could not locate executable f90

  Could not locate executable f77

  customize IBMFCompiler

  Could not locate executable xlf90

  Could not locate executable xlf

  customize IntelFCompiler

  Could not locate executable ifort

  Could not locate executable ifc

  customize GnuFCompiler

  Could not locate executable g77

  customize G95FCompiler

  Could not locate executable g95

  customize PGroupFCompiler

  Could not locate executable pgfortran

  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

  C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g



  compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'

  gcc: _configtest.c

  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

  failure.

  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/setup.py", line 394, in <module>

      setup_package()

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/setup.py", line 386, in setup_package

      setup(**metadata)

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup

      return old_setup(**new_attr)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup

      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

      dist.run_commands()

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands

      self.run_command(cmd)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command

      cmd_obj.run()

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run

      r = self.setuptools_run()

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run

      return distutils_install.run(self)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run

      self.run_command('build')

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

      self.distribution.run_command(command)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command

      cmd_obj.run()

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run

      old_build.run(self)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run

      self.run_command(cmd_name)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

      self.distribution.run_command(command)

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command

      cmd_obj.run()

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run

      self.build_sources()

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources

      self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources

      sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

    File "/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources

      source = func(extension, build_dir)

    File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info

      raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

  RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

  ----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-yyq4ehg0/numpy_7ce430e3481440c8b99380c6e103958b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-record-xmqdnd8z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-9eve9y_3/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-9eve9y_3/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.

---

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/d0/55bbb49f4fade3497de2399af70ec0a06e432c786b8623c878b11e90d456/Bottleneck-1.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=451586370462cb623d6ad604a545d1e97fb51d2ab5252b1ac57350a83e494a28 (from https://pypi.org/simple/bottleneck/). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-c10se9ft/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-9eve9y_3/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.

Using cached Bottleneck-1.3.0.tar.gz (87 kB)

Installing build dependencies ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-32xvuay6/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-1px47p94/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''

```
   cwd: None
```

Complete output (262 lines):

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "2.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "2.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

Collecting setuptools

```
Using cached setuptools-58.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (816 kB)
```

Collecting wheel

```
Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
```

Collecting numpy==1.14.5

```
Using cached numpy-1.14.5.zip (4.9 MB)
```

Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, numpy

```
  Running setup.py install for numpy: started

  Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-tz8kx32d/numpy_a62d55302d97422ebb650ab6d64c8d74/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-tz8kx32d/numpy_a62d55302d97422ebb650ab6d64c8d74/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-record-14wh10mv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-1px47p94/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-build-env-1px47p94/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy

       cwd: /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-tz8kx32d/numpy_a62d55302d97422ebb650ab6d64c8d74/

  Complete output (239 lines):

  Running from numpy source directory.



  Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install

  with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:



    - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source

                             release)

    - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)





  /private/var/folders/nr/lpcxf08x1jd10vh4wlx7h1240000gn/T/pip-install-tz8kx32d/numpy_a62d55302d97422ebb650ab6d64c8d74/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:464: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)

  blas_opt_info:

  blas_mkl_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  blis_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries blis not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

    NOT AVAILABLE



  openblas_info:

  customize UnixCCompiler

  customize UnixCCompiler

    libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
```

...

Comment: Update your question with complete error to understand what causing the issue. It normally works when you upgrade the setuptools. **pip install --upgrade setuptools**

Comment: The question is not specific IMO.